# Weird error with contains jquery

Tags: jquery, contains

I have an array and its built correctly:

```
//Clients list
clientsList = [];

$('.client__name').each(function() {
    clientsList.push( $(this).html().toLowerCase() );
});
```

I'm trying to get those which contain a specific string:

```
$( clientsList:contains('string') ).each(function() {
    console.log('result');
});
```

But I have this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

I have no idea about what's wrong, any idea?.

Comment: I don't know that this is impossible (I've not read the [`:contains()`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector) documentation in a while) but you appear to be trying to select Array elements using the contains-selector, which I don't think can work, and the `:` is a syntax error outside of object-construction to the best of my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

clientsList is an array.  You should use the `$.each` method for arrays.

```js
$.each( clientsList, function( client ) {
    if (client.indexOf('string') > -1) console.log('result');
});
```

Comment: It would be better to just filter in the CSS selector then write extra code filtering on top of the CSS selector.

Comment: It's not a dom lookup.  He has an array with results he wants to filter.  Or do you mean do that filter before adding to the array in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

"contains" is a selector keywords, not an array function.
this is the right way:

```
$(".client__name:contains('string')").each(function() {
    clientsList.push( $(this).html().toLowerCase() );
});
```

Comment: what if he wants to match on 'string' case insensative?

Answer (score -1):

```
$(".client__name:contains('string')").each(function() {
    console.log('result');
});
```

Comment: contains() doesn't match case insensitive does it?  If you look in the OP he's lower casing the value before the second part tries to find the matches. @ism

Answer (score -1):

```
$(clientsList).each(function(i) {
    console.log(clientsList[i].contains("string"))
})
```

Comment: `$.each()` should be used with arrays not containing dom elements, not `$.fn.each()` which is what $(...).each() is